# How far does Gameboy Advance SP's backwards compatibility go?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, game-boy-advance

What other systems' games does the Gameboy Advance SP support?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Game Boy Advance SP can play **Game Boy Advance** games, **Game Boy Colour** games, and **Game Boy** games. ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Boy_Advance_SP))

Comment: The caveat is that because of the GBA cartridge size, the GBC and GB games will stick out significant amount from the system.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlheqG-jpiA) shows what it would look like.